# PyroCMS Relationship Field Memory Overflow

Tags: php, codeigniter, stream, relationship, pyrocms

I have a relationship field with 16,000 possible values in the related table.

For example, I have have a pets stream with one relationship to my pet_owners stream.   There are 16,000 possible pet owners.

Whenever I try to create or edit a 'pet', I get an error that we've run out of memory.  It also happens when I try to add a page of type 'pets list' that is related to the pets stream.

Basically, any time it is supposed to show a drop down list of pet owners, my application will crash.  How can I fix this?

See screenshot and question on stack overflow: [image]

Comment: Wait, so you want a dropdown with 16,000 options in it??

Comment: No, something different like a search box.   This all core PyroCMS code.  I thought that they would be able to handle a related table with a decent amount of entries.  I was hoping for a workaround or tips on the easiest way to update the core functionality.

Comment: Yeah, something like an [autocomplete](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+autocomplete) would be better as mentioned below. (Do you want everyone to be able to see the names of everyone else in the system though? Possible security implications there.) At any rate, I don't think the problem is that there are a lot of rows, but that you are trying to *render* so many rows. Usually there is some type of pagination or some other mechanism (e.g. autocomplete) to handle rendering large datasets.

Comment: Only admin has access to insert records so I don't mind if all names show up.  I will take a look at possibly using a different rendering technique.  ty

Answer (score 0):

Just don't show a dropdown box, it'll try to load ALL of your data. 16,000 options.

I recommend you to use a textfield with autofilling when typing, this can be done by jQuery/AJAX and will limit your data request. This will search for everything beginning with the letter s when typing it, and so on till you got the result the user where searching for.

Answer (score 0):

For now I solved it by creating an addon field type "Big Relationship" based upon relationship.  Then in the db SELECT query I added only the id and $titleField.